# Why can't date and regexes in Python be as succinct as they are in JS?

Tags: javascript, python

1. Why is `datetime` a "child" of itself? Why is it `datetime.datetime.now` instead of `datetime.now`?
2. Why can't I use regex literals like in Javascript? EG `/foo/.test('foo')`

Comment: datetime is not a child of itself, it's a child of date. As for js, why can't I use dictionaries in js like I can in Python? They simply aren't the same language.

Comment: Different languages have different features, strengths, weaknesses, and styles. Why can't JS be as fast as C? Why doesn't JS have an interactive interpreter like Python? Why doesn't JS have a range() function?

Comment: @Russel: Use Coffeescript for the latter two ;)

Comment: Oh! Oh! Why can't string slicing be as succinct in JS as in Python?

Comment: Why can't one language have all the cool features of other languages?

Answer (score 3):

**datetime is  a `python module` that `contains datetime class` that has a method `now`.**

I agree with you datetime.datetime only looks ugly because the module and class have the same name . I have myself been stumped at times due to this specific issue.

I have mostly incorporated the class directly in my module by doing.

```
from datetime import datetime  <-- the first datetime is module and second a class
....
datetime.now()   <------ this datetime is a class
```

Comment: Seems unnecessary to type datetime twice.

Comment: See my answer. datetime is a class in the datetime module. They could have called the module or the class something different, but they didn't

Comment: It's clearly *necessary* to type datetime twice, because it doesn't work if you don't. How do you refer to a method in a class in a module in Javascript?

Comment: @Russell Borogove : See multiple answers that has been posted here. Specially Falmarri and Roadmaster's answer. you could always make that simpler by using the approach : from module import class ...then just use class.method ...

Answer (score 1):

1. `datetime.now()` (where `datetime` is a class and `.now()` is a static method of this class) is perfectly possible. You just have to `from datetime import datetime` (where the first `datetime` is a module of the standard library -- python likes namespaces very much -- and the second the said class in that module). It's just not common.
2. Design decision. I suppose it complicates the grammar quite a bit (it sure looks like it does) and it's also not clearly superior - forward slashes must be escaped, the alternatuve (raw string literals) don't need backslashe escaping, so they're about even. Also, Python (unlike e.g. Perl, where regex literals come from as far as I know) is *not* solely a scripting language for e.g. text processing. I've written several Python modules a hundred lines long that didn't use a single regex.

Comment: +1, Python isn't a scripting language, and regex's should only be used when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For 1. you could do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now() #thus saving "datetime"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a namespace. You can change that

```
[~]
|4>from datetime import datetime

[~]
|5>givemethetime = datetime.now

[~]
|6>givemethetime()
[6] datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 10, 12, 27, 20, 872721)
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has some great strengths, but namespaces aren't really seen as one of its strengths (there are workarounds as mentioned in the book:  *Javascript: the good parts*).

As mentioned by others, isn't date succinct if you do: **from datetime import datetime**?